# Removing items from databound listview : Possible bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I not remove items from a databound listview?

I bind the list view to a collection of users. lets say the listview is displaying name/address from the test object. If I try to remove the first item as below, it still displays all the records in the collection. This does not serve any good purpose. I just want to know what am I missing.

I'm suspecting it is because the datasource is still pointing to the collection which is unchanged. but if I manually change the listview items, shouldn't it take precedence?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       lvTest.DataSource = new List<TestObj>{ obj1, obj2..}; //pseudo code
       lvTest.DataBind();

       lvTest.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I understand this is not a good way of doing this. But the purpose of this question is to know why this does not work.

I think this might be a bug in the listview control. If you check the items count in the debugger after the first item is removed, you can see that the actual count is reduced by 1, but it still renders it.

Also, if you did `lvTest.Items[0].Visible = false;` after the `RemoveAt(0)`, it actually makes the second item invisible which means that listview considers the first item removed but renders it regardless.

**Update 2**

On request, markup and codebehind used for test are below.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvTest" runat="server" >
            <LayoutTemplate><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" /></LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div><%# Eval("CompanyName")%><hr /></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate><div>None</div></EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvTest.DataSource = GetCompanyList();

            lvTest.DataBind();

            lvTest.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}



public static List<Company> GetCompanyList()
        {
            List<Company> c = new List<Company>();

            Company c1 = new Company();
            c1.CustomerID = "2122";
            c1.ContactName = "testc1";
            c1.CompanyName = "test2";

            Company c2 = new Company();
            c2.CustomerID = "2123";
            c2.ContactName = "testc2";
            c2.CompanyName = "test2";

            c.Add(c1);
            c.Add(c2);

            return c;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using mvvm? In that case you might want to send notification as well.

Comment: just regular asp.net, has a listview on the page and this code in the codebehind.

Comment: Can't you remove the data you want to remove before it binds?

Comment: you can't. it will throw an exception as there won't be any items before it binds. i tried. if you meant the collection, no, i need to remove the item this way. Like I mentioned, i'm curious why it does not work.

Comment: Just for curiosity can u show your real code and not pseudo one? can you show markup and whole code behind? if you remove at 0 before databind and debug this what do you see?

Comment: updated. If i used removeat before databind, it will throw an exception as there are no elements in lv yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should be able to. As I understand it, the databinding is purely a process to populate the entries on the listview, so removing them after should work.

However, if this is what you want to do, a databound list does not seem like the right answer. Either get the data first, modify it, and populate the listview with the amended list; or amend the datastream to reflect jsut what you need - which you say is not an option.

What you are saying is that you want it to be databound, but you don't have a data source that actually matches the list you require. This means it should not be databound.

Another possibility that might be interesting is to use javascript/jquery to remove the items, which migh indicate whether this is a rendering problem or an object problem.

Comment: Your first line is what my thought is and i'm perplexed by why it does not work. On to your second point, i agree with what you are saying. but I have a weird scenario, where I need to remove a particular item after it is databound based on some condition. Forget the need, i'm just trying to understand why this does not work. I agree this is not the right approach.

Comment: OK, I accept this, but sometimes when something doesn't work right, it is an indication that the design is wrong, but I accept your point. ANother solution has been added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to rebind the list with:

```
lvTest.DataBind();
```

Comment: That would work if OP was removing the item from the datasource, but it looks like it's being removed from the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, try binding the ListView only on the first page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lvTest.DataSource = new List<TestObj>{ obj1, obj2 ..};
        lvTest.DataBind();
    }

    lvTest.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: it should be present in the first page load. there is no postback action on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing it from the datasource?

```
List<TestObj> l = lvTest.DataSource;
l.RemoveAt(0);
```

I don't think you can remove the items directly from the listview - they have to be removed from the bound datasource.

Another way to populate the listbox is with a loop and add it to the items:

```
    List<string> l = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"};
    //this.listBox1.DataSource = l;
    foreach (string s in l)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

You should be able to use the RemoveAt now with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List data = new List<TestObj>{ obj1, obj2..}; //pseudo code
lvTest.DataSource = data;
lvTest.DataBind();
// if you want to remove, remove from data source and rebind 
data.RemoveAt(0)
lvTest.DataSource =data;
lvTest.DataBind();
```

if you remove item from list view it will remove item from list view item collection but you already data blinded to list view with fist items, until you rebind, those items will display in the list view.

But when rebinding what is happening is it take data from data source not from list view items. again it will rebind fist items because list view remove not doing any change on data source.

best way is update the data source and rebind it.

Comment: i know i can remove it from the source, but curious why it does not work straight with list view.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this type of thing.  Give this a try (VB but you get it)

```
for i as int = lvTest.Items.count -1 to 0
lvTest.Items.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

There seems to be problems when the items in the list have to "reposition" themselves.